# How do I migrate tuleap from one machine to another?

Tags: tuleap

First off, thanks to the Tuleap devels for an amazing product and making it available to the community in general. Tuleap's features are an almost perfect fit for our requirements of a tool to manage our development process. We are in the process of deploying it for a hands-on evaluation and understanding it better. At some stage we will be moving it onto a production server.

In this context, I would like to understand how to effectively back-up/transfer Tuleap from one machine to another. From [the backup instructions in the admin guide](https://tuleap.net/doc/en/administration-guide/backup.html) and the [backup instructions in the installation checklist](https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=TuleapInstallationChecklist&group_id=101#Miscellaneous), I understand that /var/lib/{mysql,tuleap,mailman}, /etc/{tuleap,mailman}, /home/{*projectdirs*} will need to be backed up in the original machine.

My questions specifically are

1. Are the directories listed above an exhaustive list or is there anything I have missed?
2. On the new machine, is it enough to just copy over the directories and install the mysql database and then Tuleap, or is there anything further to be done?

Thanks for any help.